# mysql:store procedure iterate select result inside a loop

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to get all the subcategory levels from a category in a stored procedure in mysql. But i just read cursors can't be used inside a while loop. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

```
declare element varchar(150);
declare bDone INT;
declare remain varchar(256) default concat(category, ',');
while remain != '' do
    set element = substring_index(remain, ',', 1);
    declare curs CURSOR FOR  select id from product_categories where product_categories.parent_id = element;
    declare CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
    .
    .
    .
end while;
```

product_categories has these fields:

- id
- name
- parent_id

Comment: What is the max category deep?

Comment: There isn't max category deepp, i want it generic